# Customized Layout with Usage of Section and Aside

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013

I would like the aside to be to the right side and the section to be left side. Everything should be in the middle of the space.

Please take a look at this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x14U.gif)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#main {
 width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

.righttt{
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;

}

section {

overflow: left;

}


</style>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
    <h1>City Gallery</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="main">
        <section>
        <h1>London</h1>
        <p>
        London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
        with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
        </p>
        <p>
        Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
        its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
        </p>
        </section>

        <section>
        <h1>London</h1>
        <p>
        London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
        with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
        </p>
        <p>
        Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
        its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
        </p>
        </section>

        <aside class="righttt">
        <h1>London</h1>
        <p>
        London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
        with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
        </p>
        <p>
        Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
        its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
        </p>
        </aside>    
    </div>

    <footer>
    Copyright © W3Schools.com
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}

#nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

#section {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
}

#aside {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

#article {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        Header    
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
       Navigation
    </div>
    <div id="section">
        Section
    </div>
    <div id="aside">
        Section
    </div>
    <div id="article">
        Article
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> - jsFiddle demo</title>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">  
<style type="text/css">
#main {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
section {
  overflow: left;
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}

 .righttt {
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>City Gallery</h1>
</header>
<div id="main">
    <section>
    <h1>London</h1>
    <p>
    London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
    with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
    </p>
    <p>
    Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
    its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
    </p>
    </section><aside class="righttt">
    <h1>London</h1>
    <p>
    London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
    with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
    </p>
    <p>
    Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
    its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
    </p>
    </aside>

    <section>
    <h1>London</h1>
    <p>
    London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
    with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
    </p>
    <p>
    Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
    its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
    </p>
    </section>


</div>
<div style="width: 100%;float: left;  text-align: center;"><footer>
Copyright © W3Schools.com
</footer></div>
</body></html>
```

try this code. Are you try this?  https://jsfiddle.net/zc15jeLd/1/

Comment: IS it possible to make the section to be closer?

Comment: I would like everything to be have width 800 inside of a content <div id=content>.
The content that is a layout is located in the center and still you have section to the left och asisde to the right. The wide is not 100 %, it is 800 px. Please tell me if you need more information

Comment: change the style 100% to 800px. and set 'margin:auto;'